# Can't create an all in one share option

Tags: java, android, button, share

I have created a floating button and give it id fab
When people will click on it every share option that is installed in the mobile will pop up at once and the user can choose where to share the URL.
I created it through intent but it's not working rather crashing. please help me. Give me a small piece of code.

main_activity java

```
Button buttonDonor;
Button buttonInfo;
Button needBlood;


public static String donorId = "no";
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;

public static Double lat = 0.0;
public static Double lng = 0.0;

private final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS = 1;

GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
LocationManager locationManager;
LocationListener locationListener;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    // Connecting to the database
    database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("donors");

    /**
     * Wiring up every thing
     */

 //sharebutton

    buttonInfo = (Button) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    buttonInfo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            i.setType("text/plain");
            i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Sharing URL");
            i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "http://google.com");
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, "Share URL"));
        }
    });






    buttonInfo = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_info);
    Animation slideUpAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(),
            R.anim.information);
    buttonInfo.startAnimation(slideUpAnimation);
    buttonInfo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Information.class));


        }
    });
    buttonInfo = (Button) findViewById(R.id.developer);
    Animation slideUpAnimation1 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(),
            R.anim.developer);
    buttonInfo.startAnimation(slideUpAnimation1);
    buttonInfo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, About.class));
        }
    });
    buttonInfo = (Button) findViewById(R.id.request);
    Animation slideUpAnimation2 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(),
            R.anim.request_blood);
    buttonInfo.startAnimation(slideUpAnimation2);
    buttonInfo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, RequestBlood.class));
        }
    });

    buttonInfo = (Button) findViewById(R.id.check_request);
    Animation slideUpAnimation3 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(),
            R.anim.check_request);
    buttonInfo.startAnimation(slideUpAnimation3);
    buttonInfo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, RequestList.class));
        }
    });

    needBlood = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_need_blood);
    Animation slideUpAnimation4 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(),
            R.anim.need_blood);
    needBlood.startAnimation(slideUpAnimation4);
    needBlood.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, NeedBlood.class));


        }
    });


    buttonDonor = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_donor_profile);
    Animation slideUpAnimation6 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(),
            R.anim.be_donor);
    buttonDonor.startAnimation(slideUpAnimation6);
    if (donorId.toString().equals("no")) {
        buttonDonor.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, DonorForm.class));
            }
        });
    } else {

    }

    /**
     * Initializing variable
     */
    try {
        donorId = sharedPreferences.getString("id", "no");

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    if (mGoogleApiClient == null) {
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();
    }

    locationListener = new LocationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            lat = location.getLatitude();
            lng = location.getLongitude();
        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

        }
    };

    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

    if (!locationManager.isProviderEnabled(GPS_PROVIDER)) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Please Turn on Location", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
        MainActivity.this.startActivity(myIntent);
    }


    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        /**
         * Crating a location request
         */


        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,
                new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS);


        return;
    }
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(GPS_PROVIDER, 1000, 1, locationListener);


}

protected void onStart() {
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    super.onStart();
}

protected void onStop() {
    mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
    super.onStop();
}

@Override
public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {

}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

}






boolean doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = false;

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (doubleBackToExitPressedOnce) {
        super.onBackPressed();
        return;
    }

    this.doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = true;
    Toast.makeText(this, "Please click Back twice to exit", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = false;
        }
    }, 2000);
}




}
```

Comment: what the Exception you are getting ?

Comment: crashing the app

Comment: post logcat here.

Comment: pls check below

Comment: check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Issue at `buttonInfo = (Button) findViewById(R.id.fab).` Because fab is **FloatingActionButton** and you cast it to Button type.

Replace your share code portion. Like,

```
FloatingActionButton fabBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.fab);
fabBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        i.setType("text/plain");
        i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Sharing URL");
        i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "http://google.com");
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, "Share URL"));
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

> Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton cannot be cast to android.widget.Button
>       at com.nissan.dnmcbloodbank.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:72)

Replace this line

`Button buttonInfo;`

with

```
FloatingActionButton buttonInfo;
```

and this line

```
buttonInfo = (Button) findViewById(R.id.fab);
```

with

```
buttonInfo = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
```